# PHP sign string with private key and verify with public

Tags: php

I need your help in PHP. I am noobie in it:) So the main issue: I can not verify my signature with public key, so when I do `openssl_verify` I've got an exception. My string what I want to sign is `generateDataString()` function output (all in one row):

> 0041011003008008234567890051234500210003EUR017Pangakonto
>   omanik01150060807439005makse062http://localhost:8080/www/banklink/banklink/banklink/maksa.php062http://localhost:8080/www/banklink/banklink/banklink/maksa.php0242016-09-13T11:17:00+0300005UTF-8003EST

So, in the first step I get my string, which is needed to be signed. Then I print it out. Then generating a signature and print it out too (as is). Then I encode the signature to base64 and print it out. Then I decode it back from base64 and print it out again (I did all printings to illustrate/debug). The last step I do, I take the decoded signed string and try to verify it with public key ... but it fails. So... help me please.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
// Associative array with data
$vkField = array(
        'VK_SERVICE' => '1011',
        'VK_VERSION' => '008',
        'VK_SND_ID' => '23456789',
        'VK_STAMP' => '12345',
        'VK_AMOUNT' => '10',
        'VK_CURR' => 'EUR',
        'VK_NAME' => 'Pangakonto omanik',
        'VK_REF' => '50060807439',
        'VK_MSG' => 'makse',
        'VK_RETURN' => 'http://localhost:8080/www/banklink/banklink/banklink/maksa.php',
        'VK_CANCEL' => 'http://localhost:8080/www/banklink/banklink/banklink/maksa.php',
        'VK_DATETIME' => '2016-09-13T11:17:00+0300',
        'VK_ENCODING' => 'UTF-8',
        'VK_LANG' => 'EST'
);

$preferences = array(
        'bank_private_key' => 'bank_private.pem',
        'bank_certificate' => 'bank_certificate.pem'
);

// Generate string from associative array (vkField)
function generateDataString() {

    global $vkField;
    $data = '';
    foreach($vkField as $field => $value){
        $str_length = strlen("$value");
        $data .= str_pad($str_length, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . $value;
        $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8');
    }
    return $data;
}

echo "<br/>";
echo "String in UTF-8 format: " . "<br/>";
echo generateDataString();

// Generate signature
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private (
    file_get_contents ($preferences['bank_private_key'])
);

if (!openssl_sign (generateDataString(), $signature, $key)) {
        trigger_error ("Unable to generate signature", E_USER_ERROR);
}

echo "<br/>" . "<br/>" . "<br/>";
echo "Signature as it is: ";
echo "<br/>";
echo $signature;
echo "<br/>" . "<br/>" . "<br/>";
echo "Encoded signature to base64: " . "<br/>";
$signature = base64_encode($signature);
echo $signature . "\n" . "<br/>" . "<br/>";
echo "Decoded signature from base64: ";
$signature = base64_decode($signature);
echo "<br/>";
echo $signature;


echo "<br/>" . "<br/>" . "<br/>";
echo "Verify signature:" . " " . "<br/>";
$key2 = openssl_pkey_get_public (file_get_contents ($preferences['bank_certificate']));
if (!openssl_verify (generateDataString(), $signature, $key2)){
    echo "Invalid signature";
}

echo "<br/>" . "<br/>" . "<br/>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

private key:

> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCUMIz8mPepfK6l
>   MxDK+Zh1M7iMx2Ia43zc+lJzEMpw9gqmYht7OllzM7s3Q9wShxMQxkP1slSAsRDR
>   zSoMIRRn8K4PXoJh9QB5YdtnZpQ7r+joP1INnn8Wz2D/JnwVVdgqghaxgF6XhnLe
>   sOx6vUvnLVsb9qayf1fLOGAomyIVs+X8aRzekzTVTp20SYR7cBo8SpwU3Kgi4qBK
>   ufkup7gO1ri97dqn/fd1uFekfXTsC46A0saSpsEL9zlOKo+cM5xJQPvy9y8yvEZQ
>   1jOcgtykkOGZez44a1DNFiW9pZRMJbIpskUDfZiroNmqSFmoUsfA2Gvw+4p3P9iQ
>   nd4ZylP7AgMBAAECggEAewcHtZolWr+ZmqsXkPvA1+S1naLWTu54NllX5BGXkEqk
>   MtgWaqrZomvbTRl4dqVPbci8mRmRUDowdY24D9PSxiwpxba31i16VEuqxGCERj1X
>   xqDzNT1V05EdvRatQ2U+jqPrxTeG0JOdgEYwPgI0Jtwf3MpcQKq6L4xBQNTyakLj
>   2vXuqcGF8VGAt90BdYkLHQkIG5jabkYEBhZS6glWVNmF+FLkWbHHhuqfeVicYuQl
>   tZQvkikdtrtS8cve4t4alt8JEkZP5MaOKwLvpQZamNszJmky2qFfqM8luh4UKKaM
>   sQK8jmdMK22wdvH0KQPmTKC+nC/fjGl4DKdP9nXyCQKBgQDs2q5rczEM4dIED2oo
>   l4152s9S/FuC4uQxAPe9zU8bZueTPRyoGkWsBF6usFArPfEimauthhhkZZVJ0h26
>   aIXWCAG6HEs4Eulhl8IVcVWKOuwDhJr6dPypgnw3XyRj9oOZxQcInaIs9hxTQhQp
>   AE9+aBnZxEshVpsFvPGzdLTbDQKBgQCgKxkfHaBBZHHbth0A8oemdtBX/mtoZVri
>   R8a3RfrmDgMXn7TzFqDfJGIpBuJNx9QFWg5649qNYG+x2hK2A1HeE7GtGW9zwxkk
>   ExPLeNDjIZrpVoZTTOtETMQ8pY/hrQSLE9e0tiB6xETSuIluk1tuMc4FfNHHzpY1
>   EtPSsE+JJwKBgQDXwzpCrdPQDWLYygYF5lE94SMeUL84U2JWdbA5We8nYi2wxmn1
>   hMFVO0HZVsohKjMhNuXalB5iTtuZPOxR5GePGwoftSicczXg7nMiP3USECzx43me
>   kLWd4T0w393xph4qFP8cTSTwWl5hRf/BfgPsff6Wjyd1vkRIDOANf1JFfQKBgDOz
>   lclgg9F3/fThRV1/7F/ErJ4q5zrstLikWLXiZgoK7d6bVAq//C/ri7AYo8Zdwcf0
>   eQYcNPk77vInJbERQ0T/cHQi6MIicSQe8F3W4v7eYyX9IyESjEMg0JuPCfHcKsJG
>   JnQT8koOvvSSUvKZqILamtlUoFbyDbSWHkA9X38zAoGBAL5NQy6VxV4ey3aTk31b
>   rrGNbXxKR4JuaP3gJIlA8bf3QTjTmyJO/gAYVoQQZebUb4Xmp6tUupIu1dW2xTdk
>   6hC+vKM2+1jiN4AjQ0hWDRRfatftWzPowm4XCFum1pUz61jAAEupawGHQ1TPhIg8
>   2QZnTbklTOv0dTRLulv9Nrv8
>   -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

public key:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDYDCCAkigAwIBAgIGAUl1tzczMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMHExCzAJBgNVBAYT
>   AkVFMREwDwYDVQQIEwhIYXJqdW1hYTEQMA4GA1UEBxMHVGFsbGlubjETMBEGA1UE
>   ChMKTm9yZGVhVGVzdDETMBEGA1UECxMKTm9yZGVhVGVzdDETMBEGA1UEAxMKTm9y
>   ZGVhVGVzdDAeFw0xNDExMDMxMjUyNTFaFw0zOTEwMjgxMjUzMDFaMHExCzAJBgNV
>   BAYTAkVFMREwDwYDVQQIEwhIYXJqdW1hYTEQMA4GA1UEBxMHVGFsbGlubjETMBEG
>   A1UEChMKTm9yZGVhVGVzdDETMBEGA1UECxMKTm9yZGVhVGVzdDETMBEGA1UEAxMK
>   Tm9yZGVhVGVzdDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAJ4OkLy7
>   EIIpfU+nKB9aFQ9UU++eYfftotXth6jsSiiBfGCcDPv692u0uHIkxmtpen9UGBM6
>   IHF8wQKQJlyHadcMptl9uGKd1rXh7Or6/yZJJnyzZKwfHurzq7BV2lNThZaMPM9H
>   bvfsjNyuCcTygxO+d5CBezlU4DoakUTA2S6NdQdNuvSEaCcSDAlEvSX3eVsfcX2A
>   TLk6obqme+SRqGctGXHMw3d4jIEXqddiufY9SsoKK2JsWes1G8fWVO11jbfCkPZ4
>   gImwII1SMR4afc1Rj9a10fyU3slx+AQlMNrCcsPOD10GpIqWxDmdtSI5gdbX15yZ
>   u1S+nwQszFrKp40CAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAEdC7H/IAVCE/ejyk
>   vTy3ebT/ui51qlg1OdtZzy9SYCjRphnSDn6Yu/JLq3kEsXQ5/41Zcl0IR1GGsl4X
>   TRzZmxUjuHLkes0YPBCyFi+SI70WNRFGe3oUIWpyWKbWk/jxtw+L/m5uD7LtHgMt
>   VlpI/hBYWh0GZvI3QYpyB44AKXIfmD9JUmHhcM84oH76Xje5EJ2kYVopDLkwDF7M
>   CjGavEpwYobOOd/Dwtouvm9NEFnXeuKPGAdmE0Z3SyI9ZUvT88r1w4SUMKGEIBFy
>   KlkO4nmRrCoGktJjOgZWRtemfLXVxKRoN+RDVntajKD+lafQ1PsPHtrSpuGwkX/1
>   hBRa/A==
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: I hope you won't use that certificate in any production environment, as you just burned it by publishing the private key.

Comment: This is the dev environment key pair. In prod i use the different keys.

Comment: Could you add the exception message?

Comment: when `if (!openssl_verify (generateDataString(), $signature, $key2)){
    echo "Invalid signature";
}` is executed the "Invalid signature" is printed out. Because it cannot verify signature with public key. This in the problem.

Comment: Your PEM public key should start with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----  and end with -----END PUBLIC KEY-----  and should be on seperate lines...  http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html